# How can I directly enter value in second column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, row, datasource

```
var result = from file in new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(gridpath).GetFiles("*.stn") select file;
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: var result = from file in new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(gridpath).GetFiles("*.stn") select file;
                     dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();

Comment: i have above code for my first column and now i want to add data to my second column without changing first column data is it possible ?

Comment: i mean i want to add row that add data to my second column only

Comment: Your DGV is bound to a list of FileInfo. All fields are write-protected. You could copy all data without binding.

Comment: how ? can you please explain

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The 2nd column contains the file size. Does it make any sense to change it??

Comment: that file size and other column is not required so i hide that and now i want to put other data on second column